# create multiple files with different names with loop?

Tags: java, file, loops

I wanted to create 5 different files with loop.

Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter("name.txt", "UTF-8");
}
```

For example I want *name1*, *name2*, ..., *name5* . But I can't enter `i` between quotes.

How to do that? If I can't do it with loop and PrintWriter, how to do that?
I'm using eclipse on Windows10.

Comment: Can't you just use concatenation? Hopefully you're doing more with your `printer` than just letting it go out of scope as soon as the loop is done.

Comment: I suggest starting with some proper Java tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++){
    String fileName = "name" + i + ".txt";
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
}
```

But this code only creates the files and immediately closes them as the variable `printer` goes out of scope on each iteration through the loop. Also the `UTF-8` is immaterial since you didn't write any data to the file.

If all you want to do is create the files you're better off with

```
for(int i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++){
    String fileName = "name" + i + ".txt";
    if (new File(filename).createNewFile())
    {
        // file created successfully
    }
    else
    {
        // error, do something appropriate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
`PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter("name" + i + ".txt", "UTF-8");`

Comment: I didn't think about it that way.

Comment: Take a look at  Jim Garrison's post for a more complete solution.